# How to remove merged content from master

Tags: git

I am using a git repository.

I accidentally merged my `master` branch with another branch by doing:

```
git checkout master 

git merge branch_245
```

But did not do any commit or push, so the merge is just present in my local repository.

Now I don't want to include the contents of branch_245 in my master. How can I undo my merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `merge` Git does a merge commit automatically, unless it cannot or you tell it not to. So in all likelihood you *did* commit.

Having said that you can
[`git reset`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html)
back to the previous commit like this

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: So if i do git reset , and git pull will i have all the latest  contents of  master  in my  local ?